# JTree database node select and display in textfield in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a `JTree` populated with a list of tasks from a database, I am trying to create a mouse clicked listener so that when a node is clicked, the id and task are displayed into `JTextfields`,

**below is my code**

```
private void jTree1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();

    try {
        String query = "select * from Task where task=" + nodeInfo + "";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String task = rs.getString("task");
            parentIdTxt.setText("" + id);
            childTxt.setText("" + task);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

My problem is that even tho my program runs without any issues, whenever I click the node nothing happens? any help in pointing out what I missed will be appreciated

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions, at minimum use `e.printStackTrace()` or log them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you get an error but you don't see it, because you don't print it, you can check the error using :

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

String should be between `'nodeinfo'` so instead you have to use :

```
String query="select * from Task where task= '" + nodeInfo + "'";
```

But you don't implement PreparedStatement correctly you can use this :

```
String query="select * from Task where task = ?";
insert.setString(1, nodeinfo);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
...
```

Comment: thank you very much, as soon as i put the stacktrace i found that i gave aa column from a different database name in, the code works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You have to repaint the textfields or update their layout so they have enough space to show the contents. Try adding the following code after setting the contents of your textfields:

```
parentIdTxt.validate();
parentIdTxt.repaint();
childTxt.validate();
childTxt.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to check if you get the `task` and the `id` correctly using `Debug` mode or just by printing them into the console.

I recomended you to test just this code in the `JTree1MouseClicked.

```
 private void jTree1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {      
      childTxt.setText(jTree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString());
}
```

that should display the selected node, that should work, then you need to check your request, I think that the problem is there

Comment: thank u , u were right about the problem, it was due to the column name being wrong